# How to easily evaluate a Arel::Nodes::Grouping to test if a scope was set up properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have a scope that boils down to the following

```
Expression.where(library_id:[1,2,3], account_id: [1337, nil])
```

When I evaluate the resulting arel relation, with `where_values_hash`, I don't see the last item:

```
q = Expression.where(library_id:[1,2,3], account_id: [1337, nil])
q.where_values_hash #=> { "library_id"=>[1, 2, 3] }
```

This is because `where_values_hash` [limits its results to items of class Arel::Nodes::Equality](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/where_values_hash). The second item is a `Arel::Nodes::Grouping`:

```
q.where_values.second.class
#=> Arel::Nodes::Grouping
```

I want to look into this item to see if the arel was configured properly[1]

```
expect(q.where_values_hash).to include({"library_id" => [1,2,3]}) # Passes
expect(q.where_values_hash["account_id"]).to include(1337) # Fails
expect(q.where_values_hash["account_id"]).to include(nil)  # Fails
```

How can I read into this 'Arel::Nodes::Grouping' in a way similar to reading the contents of `where_values_hash`?

---

[1] This is for testing: I want to test not that ActiveRecord works: I trust it does. What I want is to know that under certain circumstances the scope is configured with the proper arguments.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. Have you found a way to fix or circumvent this? 
In my case the class is `Arel::Nodes::In`, my query is something like `Post.where(blog: { name: 'hello world' })`

Comment: I'm thinking about just monkey-patching the Relation class in a RSpec support class and require it only on the specific specs I need

Comment: Oh, it seems [in Rails 4.2 this is possible](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/where_values_hash), for my case at least. The `where_values_hash` accepts a parameter to specify which table it's supposed to pull the values from. This solves it for me at least.

Answer (score -1):

Do your tests pass with:

```
Expression.where(library_id:[1,2,3]).where(account_id: [1337, nil])
```